# Using ls on many files results in error "bash: Argument list too long"

Tags: bash, ls

I am trying to populate a txt with all the names of .fits files from a folder with this command:

```
ls *.fits > output_all.txt
```

The number of .fits files in the folder is >330k and I get the error message

```
bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

How can I solve this?

Alternatively, it might be possible to avoid at all the creation of the file `output_all.txt`. I only need it to tell the [STILTS](http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/%7Embt/stilts/) tool what .fits files to merge into a large .fits file with this command

```
stilts tcat in=@output_all.txt out=table_stilts.fits icmd='keepcols "FLUX LOGLAM"'
```

If you know a way in which to tell STILTS to accept as input a directory, not a file it will solve my problem with `ls`. Tnx

Comment: Does `ls | grep .fits$ > output_all.txt` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ls *.fits`, it's the shell that does all the hard work finding the filenames that end in `.fits` and don't start with `.`.

Then it passes that list to `ls`, which sorts it (again, as shell globs already sort the list before passing to `ls`) and displays it (in columns or one per line depending on the implementation and whether the output goes  to a terminal or not) after having checked that each file exists.

So it's a bit counter-productive especially considering that:

- you forgot the `--` option delimiter, so any filename starting with `-` would cause problems.
- you forgot the `-d` option, so if any file is of type directory, `ls` would list their contents instead of themselves.
- as `ls` is a separate command from the shell (in most shells including `bash`), it ends up having to be executed in a separate process using the `execve()` system call and you end-up tripping its limit on the cumulative size of arguments and environment variables.

---

If you just need to print the list generated by the shell from `*.fits`, you can use `printf` instead which is built-in in most shells (and therefore doesn't invoke `execve()` and its limit):

```
printf '%s\n' *.fits > output_all.txt
```

That leaves one problem though:

If `*.fits` doesn't match any file, in the `bash` shell, `*.fits` is left as-is, so `printf` will end-up printing `*.fits<newline>`.

While `ls` would give you an error message about that non-existent `*.fits` file and leave the `output_all.txt` empty.

That can be changed with the `nullglob` option (which bash copied from `zsh`) which causes `*.fits` to expand to nothing instead. But then we run into another problem: when not passed any argument beside the format, `printf` still goes through the format once as if passed empty arguments, so you'd end up with one empty line in `output_all.txt`.

That one can be worked around with:

```
shopt -s nullglob
println() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\n' "$@"
}
println *.fits > output_all.txt
```

---

If you can switch to `zsh` instead of `bash`, it becomes easier:

```
print -rC1 -- *.fits(N) > output_all.txt
```

Where `N` enables `nullglob` for that one glob and `print -rC1` prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn, and importantly here: prints nothing if not passed any argument.

With `zsh`, you can also restrict the list to regular files only (excluding directories, symlinks, fifos..) using the `.` glob qualifier (`*.fits(N.)` for instance), or include hidden files with `D` (`*.fits(ND.)`)...

---

Lastly you can also always defer to `find` to find the files, but if you do need the list to be sorted and hidden files to be excluded, and avoid a `./` prefix, that becomes quickly tedious as well and you'd need GNU extensions. For example, for the equivalent of `print -rC1 -- *.fits(N.)`:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type f -printf '%P\0' |
  sort -z | tr '\0' '\n' > output_all.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a limit to how many characters are allowed on a single command line.  On a modern Linux system, it's about 2 million characters.  This may vary on other systems.

It looks as if the filenames of your *.fits files in the current directory won't fit onto a single command line.   There are many ways to deal with this, one of the simplest is to use `find` instead.  e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.fits' > output_all.txt
```

Another option is to use `perl`.  e.g.

```
perl -e 'print map { "$_\n" if -f $_ } sort glob "*.fits"' > output_all.txt
```

or:

```
perl -E 'foreach $f (sort glob "*.fits") { say $f if -f $f }' > output_all.txt
```

or even:

```
perl -E 'foreach $f (sort grep { -f } glob "*.fits") { say $f }' > output_all.txt
```

(there are many ways of doing this in perl).

Note: the `find` version **will** list hidden filenames (i.e. those beginning with a `.`) if any exist in the current dir.  The perl version **won't**.   Both versions will only print **regular files** ending in `.fits`, not directories, symlinks, named pipes, sockets, or device nodes.  The `find` output is unsorted, filenames are printed in the order they're found in the directory.  The perl version is sorted (ascending alpha sort.  BTW, perl's built-in sort function is flexible enough to sort by a variety of criteria, including the size or timestamps of a file)

BTW, perl has a [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) library module that can do recursive searches like `find` can but with the full power of perl for filtering, sorting, and manipulating any filenames it finds, and then processing those files.  `File::Find` is a core library and is included with perl.  If you only need to search for files in a particular directory, perl's `glob()` function is good enough.

---

AFAICT from skimming the `stilts` link you posted, it doesn't seem as if stilts' `in=@filename` arg can handle NUL-separated input, so if you have any .fits files with newlines embedded in the filename, you'll need to rename those files.

If `stilts` *could* handle NUL-separated list of filenames, you could use `find`'s `-print0` option or change the `\n` in the perl script to `\0` to generate a NUL-separated list.   This may not be relevant to `stilts`, but it's useful to know if you run into the same problem with other programs that can handle NUL as a separator (many programs have a `-z`, `-Z`, and/or `-0` option for this).

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.fits' -print0 > output_all.nul
```

or

```
perl -e 'print map { "$_\0" if -f "$_" } sort glob "*.fits"' > output_all.nul
```

Comment: Thanks! How is your answer different from the suggestion by Bib using `ls | grep .fits$ > output_all.txt`? Does your command do something different?

Comment: @NeStack this will include hidden files (e.g. `.foo.fits`) and will exclude directories, symlinks and anything else not a file. Also, the `ls` one would descend into subdirectories and list their contents, which this one does not. Note that both this approach and the `ls` one would fail if any of your file names have newlines. Of course, given that you are storing the result in a text file, I suspect that isn't a problem for you.